# How to cancel a process waiting to return with ptrace()

Tags: system-calls, nonblocking, ptrace

I am trying to cancel when a process calls wait(), read(), recvfrom() or similar, because if I use ptrace on it, after the PTRACE_ATTACH and later PTRACE_CONT, my tracer becomes blocked until the function in the tracee returns. Also I think it happens the same with sleep().

Would be possible to cancel the call, or reproduce a fake return?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should send a `PTRACE_INTERRUPT`. This will trigger the syscall to exit.

To do this, you need not to `waitpid` on your tracee, because that would block you (the tracer) too.

You can either have multiple threads: one that will block on the tracee, one that will "decide" to cancel the blocking syscall - e.g. a GUI thread that the user will press "cancel" (like a normal debugger, e.g. GDB).

Or you can use `PTRACE_SYSCALL` to manually diagnose every syscall the program is  doing and then decide preemptively if you wish to execute that syscall. This way you can decide to not run `wait` at all, or perhaps mock them by having your return value instead.